# Backbone - How to limit ajax requests per second or create queue?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my case, I load a collection with two requests

1. get me
2. get friends

each one makes another request(s) to get photos in the model

1. 1 request
2. 10 requests (one per friend)

Bottomline is that I have 13 requests. But server can service only 3 request per second. What should I do?

**UPD**
Remote server is not mine. Mb its wrong, but my way already was:

- collection.add(collection.getMe()) -> model.init -> model.getphotos->
  view.render() (1 time)

next

- collection.add(collection.getFriends()) ->... next for each friend ... model.init -> model.getphotos->view.render() (10 times)

I'm totally noob in backbone. I'm trying to program in the backbone style. But I cannot understand how to limit ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this at two different levels, the first being design, and the second being performance optimization.

**Design:**

Personally I would approach the problem differently by creating an api endpoint that returned all of the required data in a single request. This could involve:

1. an endpoint that returns a single object and direct dependencies (get me) and then
2. an endpoint that returns all friends of a specific object and their dependencies (get friends + photos, etc)

**Performance:**

If the reason for the question is because its already really slow then you might consider the design, but if you are only worried that it will be slow then I would move forward and measure the real-world performance. Spending time optimizing what you think might be slow could prove to be a wrong strategy.

3 requests per second could be enough and the N requests will most likely queue up and be served in succession. You might be fine.

If you are not fine, then you can change the loading of the photos (or whatever is being loaded after) on demand (when the user interacts or paginates, etc) this will ensure that you use what you pull and you only pull what you use.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your attention. i updated question text for details.